# Тип HANDLE. Как значение дескриптора записать в строку?

Tags: c++

Создаю дескриптор текстового файла `HANDLE file = CreateFile(...);`, успешно с ним работаю. 
Так вот...я могу отправить этот "`file`" в `cout`, и увижу в консоли примерно такое сообщение: `00000000000002C0`. Это всё понятно.

Но никак не могу с такой же легкостью сохранить это значение в какой-либо переменной, например, в `string` или массиве символов `char`. Как это реализовать?

Кто что может сказать по этому поводу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//1 вариант
char str[64]; //про запас
sprintf(str, "%p", file);

//2 вариант
std::stringstream ss;
ss << static_cast<void*>(file);  
std::string value = ss.str();
```

Comment: большое спасибо) это то что я искал! )

Comment: Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.

Answer (score 2):

Можно совершить поиск в заголовочных файлах и обнаружить там

```
typedef void* HANDLE;
```

Т.е. `HANDLE` - не что иное как `void*`.

Можно воспользоваться средствами C++ и вывести этот тип:

```
cout << typeid(HANDLE).name() << endl;
```

Вы увидите

```
void *
```

Т.е. ваш `HANDLE` - это просто указатель, и с ним можно делать все, что с обычным указателем. Только отдавая себе отчет, что и **зачем** :)

В строке его можно хранить, переведя в соответствующее строковое представление. Типа

```
char s[20];
HANDLE h;
sprintf(s,"%p",h);
```

Или даже просто как исходную последовательность байт:

```
unsigned char s[4];
HANDLE h;
memcpy(s,&h,sizeof(h));
```

В переменных типа `int` - *конечно, если размеры позволяют* (в 64-разрядном мире `void*` - 8 байт) - с помощью явного приведения типов `reinterpret_cast`

```
HANDLE f;
int g = reinterpret_cast<int>(f);
```

Только надо понимать, что вы делаете и зачем. Иначе можно получить неприятностей на любящую приключения точку...

Comment: Что вернет `cout << typeid(HANDLE).name() << endl;` зависит от реализации. gcc, [например](http://cpp.sh/2jcrp), выдаст `Pv`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Ну, в принципе, да, вы правы. Я писал о VC++.

Comment: спасибо за информацию )

Comment: Вместо `int` надо использовать специальные типы: `intptr_t` или `uintptr_t` из `<cstdint>`. Так как указатель вполне может не поместиться в обычный `int`.

Comment: @alexolut Да, но заказчик :) хочет размещать, если я верно его понял, вообще в *произвольных* переменных...